# Sync Ubuntu repository with Cobbler server fails

Tags: ubuntu, centos, gpg, cobbler

I am trying to sync the Ubuntu trusty repo to my cobbler server.  The issue is that for some reason the connection seems unstable during the parts that work.. additionally it fails to proceed with one of the repositories.

It seems I don't have any keys but I also can't find out how to make them for CentOS.

Machine:CentOS6.6

Cobbler Version: 2.6.7

I will be sure to update the is as soon as I find out more.

Here is my error:

```
[root@cobbler ~]# cobbler reposync --only=Ubuntu-x86_64
task started: 2015-02-20_003405_reposync
task started (id=Reposync, time=Fri Feb 20 00:34:05 2015)
hello, reposync
run, reposync, run!
running: /usr/bin/debmirror --nocleanup --verbose --ignore-release-gpg --method=http --host=archive.ubuntu.com --root=/ubuntu --dist=trusty,trusty-updates,trusty-security --section=main,universe /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Ubuntu-x86_64 --nosource -a amd64
received on stdout: Mirroring to /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Ubuntu-x86_64 from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Arches: amd64
Dists: trusty,trusty-updates,trusty-security
Sections: main,main/debian-installer,contrib,non-free,main,universe
Pdiff mode: use
Will NOT clean up.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty/Release... ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty/Release.gpg... ok
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 08 May 2014 11:20:33 PM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 17 10 00 1399558833 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 08 May 2014 11:20:33 PM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 1 10 00 1399558833 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 08 May 2014 11:20:33 PM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 08 May 2014 11:20:33 PM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty).
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/Release... ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg... ok
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 03:14:29 PM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 17 10 00 1424326469 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 03:14:29 PM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 1 10 00 1424326469 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 03:14:29 PM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 03:14:29 PM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty-updates).
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-security/Release... ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg... ok
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 06:40:25 AM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 17 10 00 1424295625 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 06:40:25 AM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
[GNUPG:] ERRSIG 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 1 10 00 1424295625 9
[GNUPG:] NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: keyblock resource `/var/lib/cobbler/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 06:40:25 AM JST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 06:40:25 AM JST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty-security).
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz... ok
[  4%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2... [  8%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2... ok
[  9%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz... ok
[ 11%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2... ok
Errors:
 Download of dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 failed: 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer
 dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 failed checksum verification, removing

received on stderr: rsync: failed to connect to archive.ubuntu.com: Network is unreachable (101)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(124) [receiver=3.0.6]
Warning: failed to use rsync to download extra files.
failed 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer
Failed to download some Package, Sources or Release files!
releasing 1 pending lock... at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LockFile/Simple.pm line 206.

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 126, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'cobbler reposync failed'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 126, in run
    self.sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 172, in sync
    return self.apt_sync(repo)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 540, in apt_sync
    utils.die(self.logger,"cobbler reposync failed")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 134, in die
    raise CX(msg)

reposync failed, tries left: 0
reposync failed, retry limit reached, skipping
running: chown -R root:apache /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Ubuntu-x86_64
received on stdout:
received on stderr:
running: chmod -R 755 /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/Ubuntu-x86_64
received on stdout:
received on stderr:
Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 126, in die
    raise CX(msg)

Exception occured: <class 'cobbler.cexceptions.CX'>
Exception value: 'overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize'
Exception Info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 87, in run
    rc = self._run(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/remote.py", line 247, in runner
    3), name=name, nofail=nofail, logger=self.logger)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/api.py", line 820, in reposync
    return reposync.run(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/action_reposync.py", line 155, in run
    utils.die(self.logger,"overall reposync failed, at least one repo failed to synchronize")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cobbler/utils.py", line 134, in die
    raise CX(msg)

!!! TASK FAILED !!!
```

Comment: You should first fix your Internet connectivity issues.

Comment: unfortunately I can't its either not a server issue or it has something to do with the debmirror script. I had a constant ping out of my environment running at the same time and only dropped 20 of the 3500 packets.  Additionally under conditions where the script is not running I have no issues with an extended ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added the keys to the gpg keychain. I am running a near identical configuration to yours (CentOS 6.6/trusty) and resolved this particular issue by passing the flag `--no-check-gpg`.

A more ideal solution would be to download and manually add the keys to your keyring.